# Prevent android Navigation Drawer from closing till a condition is met

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a NavigationDrawer having a list with many radio buttons.I want the user to have to select a list item before he can close the Drawer.
The drawer should not close till the item is selected.
Is there a clean way with which I can achieve this??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set up the DrawerLayout lock mode [setDrawerLockMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerLockMode%28int,%20int%29) as follow:

```
 mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
```

but you need to handle actionbar home up button.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend not restricting drawer operations, and just set a default selection, in case the user doesn't select an option.

However, if you insist on doing it, this method seems to be the one to go with:

```
// Belonging to DrawerLayout
public void setDrawerLockMode (int lockMode, View drawerView)
```

In `onCreate()` open it and lock it, then unlock it upon the selection of any of the options. There is no need to recheck during the usage, as radio implies there is always a selection, unlike check box selection.

That would be my first attempt at this, let me know, cheers.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerLockMode%28int,%20android.view.View%29)

Comment: this is more detailed and exact solution. Also told where to exactly call the method which saves some minutes at least. This should be accepted answer. But 'Rajul' asked the question and 'Ahmad's' answer was selected