# Navigation drawer: How do I set the navigation item selected listener with custom tool bar?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar, navigationview

I don't see any error when I open the navigation drawer, but it keeps getting closed whenever I select an item. *Edit: My drawer gets closed automatically on item selection without showing the **Toast message** as mentioned in `NavigationItemSelectedListener`. The toast message is not displayed.*
I have used a custom toolbar in which I have added an image view as a side menu button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CustomToolbar"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_file"
        app:menu="@menu/main_manu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
    
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bggradient">
    
            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```
public class CustomToolbar extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private ImageView side_menu;
    
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_toolbar);
    
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.navigation_bar);
        side_menu = findViewById(R.id.side_menu);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    
        side_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });
    
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.home_menu: {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomToolbar.this, "Home Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        case R.id.community_menu: {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomToolbar.this, "Community Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        case R.id.posts_menu: {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomToolbar.this, "Posts Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        case R.id.website_menu: {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomToolbar.this, "Website Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        case R.id.share_menu: {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomToolbar.this, "Share Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        case R.id.feedback_menu: {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomToolbar.this, "Feedback Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        case R.id.about_menu: {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomToolbar.this, "About us Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        case R.id.logout_menu: {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomToolbar.this, "Logout Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

I have tried other method with default toolbar, and it was working properly but I am not able to figur out the problem with custom toolbar. I wanted to display a toast on item selection inside the navigation drawer. Please help me find the solution...

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17510614/2649154 ?

Comment: @gioravered First of all, I am sorry for my late reply to your comment.  As you had asked me if I had tried adding `setDrawerLockMode()`. I tried it and it did sort of helped me to hold the drawer layout open.  I used it like this - First: I used `drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);` after opening the drawer layout. Second: I used `drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);` inside the **NavigationItemSelectedListener()...** to close the drawer on item selection.   But it still not showing me the Toast **"Home Selected"**  or other.

Comment: Does the Toast code execute? Are you sure it reaches the toast line when clicking the menu items?

Comment: @gioravered no it doesn't reach the Toast message. And I have tried using the try catch block and still doesn't returns any error.

Answer (score 0):

In `onNavigationItemSelected`, Change this

```
return false;
```

to

```
return true;
```

Comment: I had tried this before also and now I tried it again, and it is still not working. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

After so long finally I found the solution to my problem. But I don't know why it was happening like that but I'm happy that it is finally working. And I am also very happy to share it with those who may experience the same issue in the future which I hope they won't.

I referred to the link from the Git hub for this solution. Link: https://github.com/priyalbhatewara123/Navigation-Drawer--Android

Finally here is the solution I found,

I just added the following lines of codes below `</ScrollView>` which was above `<ScrollView>` in the problematic code used in my **activity_custom_toolbar.xml**.

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_file"
    app:menu="@menu/main_manu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>
```

I'm also adding the code after changes,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CustomToolbar"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bggradient">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_file"
        app:menu="@menu/main_manu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```